# Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'Promise'

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, mern

I have a client side problem. Server side is working fine, and the deleteCourse method deletes the course, but i get the error you see in the title on the client side. I am not sure what is going on. If i need to provide something else, just ask :D

/actions/courses.js

```
export const deleteCourse = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    await api.deleteCourse(id);
    dispatch({ type: DELETE, payload: id });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

/reducers/courses.js

```
import { FETCH_ALL, CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE } from '../../constants/actionTypes';
export default (courses = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_ALL:
      return action.payload;
    case CREATE:
      return [...courses, action.payload];
    case UPDATE:
      return courses.map((course) =>
        course._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : course
      );
    case DELETE:
      return courses.filter((course) => course._id !== action.payload);
    default:
      return courses;
  }
};
```

/api/index.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
//Our route
const API = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000' });
//Occurse before all the bellow requests
//Za google je result a za klasican je token
API.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('profile'))
    req.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile')).token
    }`;

  return req;
});
export const signIn = (formData) => API.post('/user/signIn', formData);
export const signUp = (formData) => API.post('/user/signUp', formData);
export const fetchCourses = () => API.get('/courses');
export const createCourse = (newCourse) => API.post('/courses', newCourse);
export const updateCourse = (id, updatedCourse) =>
  API.patch(`./courses/${id}`, updatedCourse);
export const deleteCourse = (id) => API.delete(`./courses/${id}`);
```

/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from '../src/api/reducers';
const store = createStore(reducers, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

/Button that starts the action

```
<Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={() => {
          dispatch(deleteCourse(course._id))}}><DeleteIcon fontSize="small" /> Delete</Button>
```

I tried to console.log deleteCourse and i see that it is a resolved promise. Now i am watching some course on youtube, and making my own project, but all of this is working for that guy just perfectly. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `deleteCourse(course._id)` returns a promise because it is `async`, so calling `dispatch(deleteCourse(course._id))` is causing your error.  The way you wrote this it seems you actually want to call something like `() => await deleteCourse(course._id)(dispatch)` in `onClick`

Comment: It doesn't work, i can't add await in onClick function. It gives error because dispatch is not async function it seams.

Comment: Do
`async () => await deleteCourse(course._id)(dispatch)`

Comment: Still doesn't work. Now says Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object(...)(...) is not a function. Funny thing is that my other functions, like creating course and getting one works just fine. I am not sure what's the problem. I call that from buttons the same as i do in this one.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was in file with button which dispatch the function. The function deleteCourse is named the same in my backend, so the import in that file was function from backend and not the proper one from /actions folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).